Using GitHub for a UE5 group project. Have run into a massive issue where .db & .ipch files are unusually large. How can I fix it and properly commit?
The error specifically is the push operation including files which exceeds GitHub's file size restriction of 100MB. Solution.VC.db, Browse.VC.db are the main files plaguing and preventing a commit as they range from 754 MB to 1 GB large. Has been a massive headache for me and my group. How can I get GitHub to properly ignore or remove these files so that I can push commits smoothly?
Have tried removing it and deleting the files off explorer and adding them to gitignore but the error persists despite this. Have even tried using and installing GitHub LFS, yet the same error over those same files persists.
